# Update's not updating all registers

Tags: sql-server-2008

I can't get this to work, hopefully you can lend me a hand.

I have a `PROCESSING` table with `10357` rows.
Then I have another one called `RESULTS` with data to be replaced in PROCESSING.

The rows in RESULTS are `1262`, and there's a unique field in both which I'll use for updating.
All those `1262` registers in RESULTS have the unique field in PROCESSING.
So, after the update there should be `1262` rows updated in PROCESSING. Right?

I built the query shown at the bottom.

After running the query I get `758 row(s) affected`
What am I doing wrong? I want all those `1262` rows to be updated.

Thanks in advance.

**Query**

```
UPDATE 
     PROCESSING 
SET
     FIELD1 = ATR.FIELD1, FIELD2 = ATR.FIELD2
FROM (
     SELECT         
        FIELD1, 
        FIELD2,
        UNIQUEFIELD
FROM
    RESULTS) AS ATR
WHERE
    PROCESSING.UNIQUEFIELD = ATR.UNIQUEFIELD
```

Comment: What is `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UNIQUEFIELD) FROM RESULTS`?

Comment: are you sure about the uniqueness data in both tables? what is the output of this query there? ( select count(*) from "processing" p, "result" r where r.uniquefield=p.uniquefield)

Comment: @MartinSmith shame on me, that's it. I didn't check that since the uniquefield is in the mayority on the tables a primary key. Now I know it's not the case in RESULTS. Please, answer the question so I can mark it as the right one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen if `UNIQUEFIELD` is not actually unique in `RESULTS`.

The corresponding row in `PROCESSING` would only be updated once and it is undeterminstic which source row would be used.